# JQuery - Drag & Drop - Id draggable element

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, draggable, droppable

I'm new in this forum

I learned jquery from 2 week and i'm fairly inexperienced.
My site is build with asp.net mvc and use jquery 1.4.1

this is the code

html

...

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Amici)
    {%> 
    <div id="amico_<%= item.Id %>" idAmico="<%= item.Id %>">
    <%= item.Name %>
    </div> 
    <% } %>
```

....

script

```
    
    $(function() {
        $("div[id^='amico_']").draggable({ revert: "valid" });
        $("#droppable").droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var index = $(".ui-draggable").attr('idAmico');
                $(this)
                   .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
                   .find("p")
                   .html("id = " + index);
            }
        });
    });
```

the problem is that id attribute's value is always 1 (index variable) while are 1 and 2. (red row)
where am i wrong?

thanks so much for your replies
Alberto

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing? In other words, what's your question?

Comment: sorry but i'm new on stackoverflow. i've the problems with copy the code HTML on post... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one quick note that may help.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Amici)
{%> 
<div id="amico_" idAmico="">
    <%= item.Name %>
</div> 
<% } %>
```

In this example, and based on your jQuery selector, I think you are expecing the id of each div to be "amico_1", "amico_2" and so on... perhaps based on the item id? In any case, the id attribute must be unique.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Amici)
{%> 
<div id="amico_<%= item.Id %>" idAmico="" class="drag">
    <%= item.Name %>
</div> 
<% } %>
```

Notice also that I have added a class of "drag" to the div.

This means your selector can be updated from this:

```
$("div[id^='amico_']").draggable({ revert: "valid" });
```

To this

$(".drag").draggable({ revert: "valid" });

And my last suggestion is that you've got a small mistake on this line...

```
var index = $(".ui-draggable").attr('idAmico');
```

It should actuall be

```
var index = $(ui.draggable).attr('idAmico');
```

You should notice that there is a parameter named ui that gets passed into your droppable event. This contains the current dragged element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i' ve modified my original question about first code block (problem with HTML on post :) ). Anyway thank so much for your replies. Try this and i will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your drop function, you are arbitrarily pulling `$(".ui-draggable")` which is any class on the page that matches this, not the child object of the object being dropped.

From the docs I found (http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop) you can access the element that was dropped with `ui.draggable`